# Callback function plotly offline in python code

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, qgis

I read about click events of the python API. There is something in javascript here https://plot.ly/javascript/lasso-selection/ but I'd like to do it in pure python (if possible).

I will try to be as clear as possible.

I'm developing a plugin in QGIS (http://qgis.org/en/site/) that will take the attributes of geographic data and use them as input for some plotly charts.

What I need is to know if it is possible to have a "back signal" of the points (or lines or whatever) selected with the lassoo selection button.

I'm trying to create a dinamic response between QGIS map canvas and the html file produced by plotly. So that the user can select points on the plot and they will be selected also on the map canvas (and viceversa).

One idea is to use the lassoo selection and get some information (point unique ID for example) and re-inject it so that QGIS will display the selected points on the map canvas.

Is there any chance to obtain a kind of signal of the plots selection and use it?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

I'd love this feature too, but I'm afraid we'll have to wait for the [`plotly.dash`](https://github.com/plotly/dash) "re-thinking" for it to be possible in python.

But it might be possible to mash together this [flask chat app](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/templates/index.html) with the [plotly example in your question](https://plot.ly/javascript/lasso-selection/).

We'd replace the `console.log` call in the callback from the plotly lasso example with a `socket.emit` from the websockets flask app:

```
graphDiv.on('plotly_selected', function(eventData) {
   console.log(eventData.points)
   socket.emit(eventData.points)
});
```

And our flask server would serve up an html template with the `socket.io` javascript for the chat app, but add to the HTML the `<DIV>` from the offline plotly plot, like this:

```
fig = graph_objs.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2])
html_div, divid, width, height = plotly.offline.offline._plot_html(
        fig, config=config, validate=False, default_width="100%", default_height=525, global_requirejs=False)
    html = '<HTML>\n<head>\n  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>\n</head>\n<body>' + html_div + '</body></HTML>'
```

I've left out the flask html/js in the string appending above, but you get the idea. If I get something working I'll update.